# Scrolling Android ScrollView to X-axis and Y-axis

Tags: android, android-activity, scrollview, android-xml

In my **Android** app I wanna use a **ScrollView** and it must be **scrollable** to both **X-axis and Y-axis**. Without using both **ScrollView** and **HorizontalScrollView** as I did cant I use one **ScrollView**  and enable both scrolls. What I did is below.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/srv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll1" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Is it possible to use just one scroll view and enable both scrolls. Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, No. 
ScrollView is for vertical scrolling, as is ListView. 
HorizontalScrollView is only for horizontal scrolling. 
To implement both x and y axis scrolling, you must use both ScrollView and HorizontalScrollView as you have done.